# Python regex, one word with n characters followed by two words with one char

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I need to filter strings that start with a word containing 3 or more characters, followed by exactly two words that have only one character. After these three words, anything can follow.

What I tried is this expression:

```
pattern = r'\w{3,}\s\w\s\w.*'
```

but it matches a string `apple wrong a b c` which is not correct (the word "wrong" has more than one char).

A complete example is here:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['apple wrong', 'apple wrong b c','apple a b correct', 'apple a b c correct']})
pattern = r'\w{3,}\s\w\s\w.*'
matches = df['text'].str.contains(pattern, regex=True)
result = df[matches]
print(result)
```

Comment: Add a `^` (beginning of string) or `\b` (word boundary) before the first `\w`: `\b\w{3,}\s\w\s\w.*`.

Comment: @InSync Still matches "apple wrong a b c"

Comment: Use a `^` then.

Comment: Great, r'^\w{3,}\s\w\s\w.*' works. Thanks

Comment: `^` represents the start of the string. This ensures that the matching pattern starts from the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `^` at the beginning should solve the problem. It makes sure that the pattern starts from the beginning.

```
pattern =  r'^\w{3,}\s\w\s\w.*'
```

Comment: This will match last word of any length, not only 1. You need to add `\b` before `.*`.